# jquery multiple dropdownlist validation

Tags: jquery

I have n number of dropdownlists with the same options and values.

I want to validate it, that only the unique value could be selected among these n dropdownlists. n is random number.

Example:

I have 3 ddl with these values:

```
<select>
<option value="apple" selected="yes"> Apple </option>
<option value="carrots"> Carrots </option>
<option value="potatoes"> Potatoes </option>
</select>
```

and I want to have unique selected values for each dropdownlist, so if you select apples and try to select apples again on another ddl, it changes a previous one to the available value or prompts an alert..

Comment: Here's a jsFiddle for you to do the homework on: http://jsfiddle.net/WQkkV/6/

Comment: thanks for the link, will do it in firebug instead..

Comment: Maybe better prohibit multiple selection of the same option? Right after option has selected make options with the same value in rest dropdowns disabled.

Comment: that would work also, how do I disable an option in ddl? you mean disable or remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
 $( function(){
    $('select').change( function(){
        current = $(this).val();
        unique = 0;
        $('select option:selected').each( function(){
            if ($(this).val() == current) unique++;
        });
        if (unique!=1) alert('not unique') ;
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<select>
    <option selected="selected" value="one">one</option>
    <option value="two">two</option>
</select>


<select>
    <option value="one">one</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="two">two</option>
</select>
```